# Display Json data with multiple levels

Tags: react-native, view, format, rendering, display

i am trying to implement an add_to_cart redux but it keeps giving me the error :TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

Not sure what i can change to make it iterable since i am only passing in the object

Reducer :

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from '../constants'

const initialState = {
    cardData: [],
    totalPrice :0
}
export default function cardItems(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART:
            return [
                ...state,
                {cardData: action.data}
            ]
        default:
            return state
    }


}
```

rootreducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import cardItems from './reducer'

export default combineReducers({
    cardItems,
})
```

homepage :

```
renderRow =({item}) =>{
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight >
    
        <View style={styles.row}>
        <Icon name="add" size ={20} style= {styles.addToCartBtn} onPress ={()=> {this.props.addToCartHandler(item.price)}} />
        
        </View>
      </View>
       </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }
```

when i console log it looks like only the price of the item is passed, so why am i getting this error

Answer (score 0):

your initial state is an object

```
const initialState = {
    cardData: [],
    totalPrice :0
}
```

then you should return an object as well like this:

```
return {
            ...state,
            {cardData: action.data}
        }
```